# How To Convert a SWF / DisplayObject to SVG data?

Tags: svg, flash

Anything out there that can transform a Swf or DisplayObject into an SVG?

Im trying to find a way to generate a large Sized JPG from a swf/vector shape.
The current jpg export() from AS3 has limits to jpg size and resolution.

so i figured i can just send SVG data to ImageMagick.

thanks!

artur

Answer (score 6):

If it's a complex SWF, you might need to decompile it using a proper tool and then import the vector assets and convert/re save them as svg.

If it's just shapes (no bitmaps/shapes), you can use the [awesome AS3SWF library](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/Shape-Export) and it's SVGhapeExporter.

Here's a quick class:

```
package {
    import com.bit101.components.*;
    import com.codeazur.as3swf.*;
    import com.codeazur.as3swf.exporters.SVGShapeExporter;
    import com.codeazur.as3swf.tags.*;
    import com.codeazur.as3swf.tags.*;

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.utils.*;


    public class SWF2SVG extends Sprite {

        private var swfFile:FileReference;
        private var svgFile:FileReference;
        private var status:Label;
        private var load : PushButton;
        private var save : PushButton;
        private var svg:XML;
        private var filename : String;

        public function SWF2SVG() {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void{
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            drawGUI();
        }
        private function drawGUI() : void {
            var vbox:VBox = new VBox(this);
            var buttons:HBox = new HBox(vbox);
            load = new PushButton(buttons,0,0,"Load SWF",selectSWF);
            save = new PushButton(buttons,0,0,"Save SVG",selectSVG);save.enabled = false;
            status = new Label(buttons,0,0,'load a SWF file');
        }
        private function selectSWF(event:MouseEvent):void{
            swfFile = new FileReference();
            swfFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,swfSelected);
            swfFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfLoaded);
            swfFile.browse([new FileFilter("SWF File (*.swf)", "*.swf")]);
        }
        private function selectSVG(event:MouseEvent):void{
            svgFile = new FileReference();
            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            bytes.writeUTFBytes(svg);
            svgFile.save(bytes,filename.replace('.swf','.svg'));
        }
        private function swfSelected(event:Event):void{
            swfFile.load();
            filename = swfFile.name;
            save.enabled = false;
        }
        private function swfLoaded(event:Event):void{
            var bytes:ByteArray = swfFile.data;
            var swf:SWF = new SWF(bytes);
            var svgExporter:SVGShapeExporter = new SVGShapeExporter(swf);
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < swf.tags.length; i++) {
                var tag:ITag = swf.tags[i];
                if (tag is TagDefineShape) TagDefineShape(tag).export(svgExporter);
            }
            svg = svgExporter.svg;
            if(svg != null){
                status.text = "ready! save the SVG file";
                save.enabled = true;
            }else status.text = "no shapes to export found";
        }

    }

}
```

You can run it [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/sPjI).

[image: SWF2SVG preview]

Comment: i made an AIR app inspired from your code: https://github.com/flying-sheep/SWF2SVG (the `.air` file is self-signed, so you have to trust me that it’s this code compiled ;))

Comment: @flyingsheep Nice work on the Air app :) saved me a lot of time in converting files back and forth... Cheers! One word of warning to save time for others, the resulting SVG files I generated (using Windows 7 and Flash CS4) didn't have any viewBox defined. This meant that they would not scale when rendering them in-browser... I was scratching my head with that one for a while - Once I added a viewBox to the SVG element in the .svg all was good ;)

Comment: cool. if you have integrated the changes into the program, could you please make a pull request with the changes?

Answer (score 0):

For server use, you can use this Python package http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyswf